# ้how to setTimeout auto click button next pages in DataTable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable, datatables

How to setTimeout auto click button next pages in `DataTable`?

What to do when the number of pages has to be shown?

Press the button to change the next page automatically.

Please help, thanks in advance!

[Here the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcXNN.png)

Here the code :

```
DataTable.ext.renderer.pageButton.bootstrap = function ( settings, host, idx, buttons, page, pages ) {
var api     = new DataTable.Api( settings );
var classes = settings.oClasses;
var lang    = settings.oLanguage.oPaginate;
var aria = settings.oLanguage.oAria.paginate || {};
var btnDisplay, btnClass, counter=0;

var attach = function( container, buttons ) {
    var i, ien, node, button;
    var clickHandler = function ( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ( !$(e.currentTarget).hasClass('disabled') && api.page() != e.data.action ) {
            api.page( e.data.action ).draw( 'page' );
        }
    };

    for ( i=0, ien=buttons.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
        button = buttons[i];
        button45 = button+1;
        setTimeout(button45.click(page), 1000);
        if ( $.isArray( button ) ) {
            attach( container, button );
        }
        else {
            btnDisplay = '';
            btnClass = '';

            switch ( button ) {
                case 'ellipsis':
                    btnDisplay = '&#x2026;';
                    btnClass = 'disabled';
                    break;

                case 'first':
                    btnDisplay = lang.sFirst;
                    btnClass = button + (page > 0 ?
                        '' : ' disabled');
                    break;

                case 'previous':
                    btnDisplay = lang.sPrevious;
                    btnClass = button + (page > 0 ?
                        '' : ' disabled');
                    break;

                case 'next':
                    btnDisplay = lang.sNext;
                    btnClass = button + (page < pages-1 ?
                        '' : ' disabled');
                    break;

                case 'last':
                    btnDisplay = lang.sLast;
                    btnClass = button + (page < pages-1 ?
                        '' : ' disabled');
                    break;

                default:
                    btnDisplay = button + 1;
                    btnClass = page === button ?
                        'active' : '';
                    
                    break;
            }

            if ( btnDisplay ) {
                node = $('<li>', {
                        'class': classes.sPageButton+' '+btnClass,
                        'id': idx === 0 && typeof button === 'string' ?
                            settings.sTableId +'_'+ button :
                            null
                    } )
                    .append( $('<a>', {
                            'href': '#',
                            'aria-controls': settings.sTableId,
                            'aria-label': aria[ button ],
                            'data-dt-idx': counter,
                            'tabindex': settings.iTabIndex
                        } )
                        .html( btnDisplay )
                    )
                    .appendTo( container );

                settings.oApi._fnBindAction(
                    node, {action: button}, clickHandler
                );
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
};

// IE9 throws an 'unknown error' if document.activeElement is used
// inside an iframe or frame. 
var activeEl;

try {
    // Because this approach is destroying and recreating the paging
    // elements, focus is lost on the select button which is bad for
    // accessibility. So we want to restore focus once the draw has
    // completed
    activeEl = $(host).find(document.activeElement).data('dt-idx');
}
catch (e) {}

attach(
    $(host).empty().html('<ul class="pagination"/>').children('ul'),
    buttons
);

if ( activeEl !== undefined ) {
    $(host).find( '[data-dt-idx='+activeEl+']' ).focus();
}
};
return DataTable;
```

Comment: Can you give a better description of what you're trying to do? Do you want it to set a timeout when the number of pages appears?

Comment: I want to auto scroll slides in Datatables from page 1 to page 2, 3 in 1 minute per page.

Comment: Pagination auto next page

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your interest in my question. <script>
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example3').DataTable({
    pageLength: 10
  });
  var pageInfo = table.page.info(),
      endInt = pageInfo.end,
      currentInt = 0,
      interval = setInterval(function(){
          table.page( currentInt ).draw( 'page' );
          currentInt++;
          if ( currentInt ===  endInt)
            currentInt = 0;
  
      }, 3000); } );
 </script>

Comment: If that code has solved your problem, please post an answer and accept it instead of putting all of that into a comment. Thanks